# How to determine the output byte[] size when using Apache Crypto?

Tags: java, cryptography

I following the example from Apache Crypto byte array encryption/decryption from the link below.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/xref-test/org/apache/commons/crypto/examples/CipherByteArrayExample.html

At line 54 it created a byte[] of size 32, but I don't understand how the author came up with that number.  I noticed it is a multiple of 16 which is the key size from line 40.  If that is the reason, why not 64, 128, and so on...

Comment: This may sound weird, but instead of asking **why** answers here you can also ask the authors. We've even had a famous cryptographer or 2 answering on the crypto Q/A site! Because in the end we can only create logical reasoning, **why** is not always logical unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `CryptoCipher` is a partial mirror of the `Cipher` instance. Using the `Cipher` instance requires Apache to implement a provider, and to use `Cipher` services, the provider needs to be signed. So it makes some sense to have a different class that has about the same API to easily switch between signed and unsigned code.

That out of the way, it seems `CryptoCipher` lacks a method called [`Cipher#getOutputSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getOutputSize(int)). That method is used to retrieve the minimum buffer size for an input plaintext. So basically it seems that they've specified a buffer size that is definitely large enough for a ~ 12 byte input string. Then they resize it using `Arrays.copyOf(output, updateBytes+finalBytes)` later (which will probably result in 16 bytes for ECB or CBC mode).

---

By the way, that example is such a piece of crap code that I don't have any high hopes for this library. Look at it and understand that this is **not** the way to perform cryptography. A key and IV are not strings, IV's should be random for each usage and included with the ciphertext. I won't even go into the single utility method `getUTF8String` that does absolutely nothing special. Where is the try-with-resources? Why is the `CryptoCipher` missing essential methods?

Comment: I did look at the `java.crypto` and notice they have `getOutputSize`.  But I wanted to understand what the apache library is trying to accomplish and you've have helped with your comment.

Comment: Well, I don't have the lib installed, but it should be easy to check if you indeed get 16 bytes of output. With that I hope that it constitutes an answer. Sorry about the ranting at the end, but such examples really get on my nerves; you should not learn bad crypto from an example of a crypto library. It's worse than many code fragments posted here and.. well, yipes.